# Errors when running a JavaFX Spark Application from a Docker Image

Tags: apache-spark, javafx, dockerfile

I am trying to run an Docker Image of a JavaFX SparkML Application. I can create an image but when it comes to running the image I get an error related to JavaFX.

This is my 1st Docker image and I would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction. I have searched online and tried a few ways to add JavaFX to my docker image but I keep getting the same error!

My Dockerfile:

```
# build
#FROM maven AS build

FROM maven:3.5.3-jdk-8 AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY pom.xml .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjfx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install apt-utils
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y curl

# Install openjfx
#RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get install -y openjfx

RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

#RUN mvn -B -e -C -T 1C org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:go-offline
COPY . .
#RUN mvn -B -e -o -T 1C verify



# package without maven
FROM openjdk

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*.jar ./bda-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

RUN chmod 777 *.jar

EXPOSE 8080  
CMD ["java","-jar","./bda-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And the resulting error:

```
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Answer (score 0):

JDK still includes JavaFX. Your stacktrace includes JavaFX classes. So I guess this is not your actual problem.

The docker image does not support a UI directly. It's just a container that is rather isolated from your local desktop.

But it seems to be possible to configure the docker container to use your local X-Server for rendering UI. I found this example: https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110

Basically, you have to install required X-Server libs into the container and configure display, network and volumes in order to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for this but I still haven't managed to get this working the example solution was a little vague. Is there a way to do this from within my POM file using the docker-maven-plugin or a better example with X.Server?